# popping up the data when we hover on table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a pop up with data which is there in a table row like the image shown in the URL(CS WHOLESALE GROCERS).

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/IhrfCsZ55PsmaxVpT8N1TIep-92eSZb5lWRx11WrVzS55CNwybtARfFIaMIXbUKd5LS1T1hOL1LVsEtRkuyazpNP_dI=w1342-h519

I have added the following angularjs code in my controller

```
app.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and added this in my html .

```
<div class="col-sm-2 tabularData" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                <dt>Status</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.status}}</dd>
                                <dt>Trade</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.trade}}</dd>
                                <dt>{{customerOrBooking}}</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.bookingCsr}}</dd>
                                <dt>L/D Svc</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.serviceType}}</dd>

                            </dl>
                        </div>
```

But i am not getting the output as in my image.

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: I am nvery new to this bootstrap and i am not sure how to do this.                 when i use the following snippet i am not getting dd {
    display: none;
}

dt {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

dt:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

dt:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

dt:hover:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

dt:hover + dd + dt {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}

Comment: What is your error? paste your complete code here

Comment: <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Empty Full Flag</dt>
        <dd class="ng-binding">E</dd>
        <dt>Equipment Class</dt>
        <dd class="ng-binding">C</dd>
        <dt>Equipment Number</dt>
        <dd class="ng-binding">MATU123456</dd>
        <dt>Equipment Type</dt>
        <dd class="ng-binding">D40</dd>
       </dl>

Comment: when i hover on some dt element the data should pop up like shown im the image

Comment: did you try tooltip of bootstrap?

Comment: i am not sure how to use that

Comment: You should edit your question and put all the info in that you now  wrote in the comments. The question should contain all the information that we need to give an answer. And you should do that before people ask for it! Always make it clear what you want to happen and what happens instead; the code you wrote; what you tried to do to correct the problem (in this case, what search terms you used on Google) etc. Only then will you get proper answers!

Comment: edited the question with all information

Answer (score -1):

Call this jquery:

```
$(function () {
   $('.subitem').attr('title', $('.statusRollup').remove().html())
   $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Now change your Div

```
<div class="item">
<div class="subitem col-sm-2 tabularData" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">Hello</div>    
</div>

 <dl class="statusRollup dl-horizontal">
      <dt>Status</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.status}}</dd>
                                <dt>Trade</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.trade}}</dd>
                                <dt>{{customerOrBooking}}</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.bookingCsr}}</dd>
                                <dt>L/D Svc</dt>
                                <dd>{{bookingData.serviceType}}</dd>
 </dl>
```

Comment: Hi rajesh .Could you please tell me how to use this tool tip

Comment: I have added the link with my answer just click on the hyperlink and there you can learn creating tooltip. Mark as answer if this is what you have been looking for

Comment: @Anil can you please post the code where you want to show tooltip and what you want to show in tooltip

Comment: @Anil I have edited my answer again... See whether its working now.

Comment: no its not working that way .what do u mean my call jquery function

Comment: You wrote a function were you are showing/hiding tooltip, but i wrote a different function. Here for subitem i have added attribute title and in that title i am displaying all AngularJS code which is placed in statusRollup and finally i removed all html markup present in table

Comment: Can you tell me whether you are getting anything in tooltip or not, when you hover your mouse in div

Comment: Can't understand what's the problem. When i tried, it showed me tooltip with curly braces[it did not show me Angular Data but rather showed what ever was there in dt tag]. Do one thing, once you comment your Jquery which you wrote for showing tooltip and use my jquery and my edit which i made and see whether this time its showing tooltip or not.